# Howto delete every second and third element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to delete every second and third element from an array in Javascript.

My array looks like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "yellow", "23", "Orange", "orange", "12", "Apple", "green", "10"];
```

Now I want to delete every second and third element. The result would look like this:

```
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

I tried to use a for-loop and splice:

```
for (var i = 0; fruits.length; i = i+3) {
    fruits.splice(i+1,0);
    fruits.splice(i+2,0);
};
```

Of course this returns an empty array because the elements are removed while the loop is still executed.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: There's a couple of things wrong, particularly that this is the equivalent of running `while(fruits)`, which will run for as long as fruits evaluates to true, instead of just going through the array once.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could approach this from a different angle and `push()` the value you don't want deleted into another Array:

```
var firstFruits = []

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i = i+3) {
    firstFruits.push(fruits[i]);
};
```

This approach may not be as terse as using `splice()`, but I think you see gain in terms of readability.

Comment: I'd prefer the first over the second, as the second will produce an array like `["Banana","","","Orange","","","Apple"]`

Comment: @Robert, you're absolutely right. I'm sure that's not functionality the OP desires. Thanks, I'll update my response to just include the first one.

Comment: Wow, that's easy. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 12):

You could use filter:

```
var filtered = [
   "Banana", 
   "yellow", 
   "23", 
   "Orange", 
   "orange", 
   "12", 
   "Apple", 
   "green", 
   "10"
].filter(function(_, i) {
    return i % 3 === 0;
})
```

Returns:

```
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

Comment: I like this approach using filter. But isn't `(i+1)%3 != 0 && (i+1)%2 != 0` the same as `i % 3 === 0` in this case? I think the latter is much more simple.

Comment: Best answer imo. If you want to make it look even more pretty you could write `.filter((_, i) => i % 3 === 0)`.

Comment: @Clemens: true, but unfortunately not compatible with IE11. Which is an immortal zombie specifically in larger companies. Which have the money to pay serious development. So sad (citing DT).

Answer (score 11):

This works for me.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "yellow", "23", "Orange", "orange", "12", "Apple", "green", "10","Pear","something","else"];

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruits.splice(i+1,2);
}

//fruits = Banana,Orange,Apple,Pear
```

Here's a demo that illustrates it a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/RaRR7/

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the array in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just copying the first, fourth, and seventh elements to a new array? It isn't very memory efficient but it'll still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move through the array backwards, then if `i % 2 == 0 || i%3 == 0` then splice the element from the array